# Are there regions or dialects which use both "tú" and "vos"?

Tags: voseo, pronombres, diferencias-regionales

In my experience most places use either "tú" or "vos" for the second person singular intimate/informal pronoun.

But I haven't been to every Spanish speaking country and area. Are there places which use both? And if so how does the usage differ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is. I grew up in a city in Colombia called Cali. There we have the "Valluno" accent. We widely use *vos* and *tu* in almost the same proportion not exclusively as in other "Voseo" countries and it is used in the entire *Valle del Cauca* region.

There are other countries where it is used such as Bolivia and Chile. In the case of Bolivia it is used in Santa Cruz, Beni, Pando and Tarija.

In Ecuador it is sometimes used, but I lived 7 years there and can attest that *voseo* use is fairly rare.

Below I let you for further reading and a nice geographical map with the regions that use it and those that do not. As well as those that use both!

Here is the map with the regions where both are used (shown in light blue and normal blue. Dark blue is where *vos* is predominant)

You can see according to the map that both are used in central America, Chile, a region in Colombia (Valle del Cauca, Antioquia, Eje cafetero) and a region of Ecuador (Esmeraldas)

[image: Map of regions of voseo]

[Voseo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo#Countries_where_both_forms_are_used)

Updated map
[image: Updated map]
[image]

Comment: In Guatemala I always heard "tú" but later when I was with people who had had a few drinks they would often start using "vos". This made me wonder whether they only used "tú" with us foreigners because they knew we were learning and it's more standard. Or whether "vos" is even more intimate/informal than "tú"?

Comment: I heard it a good amount of 'vos' in Cochabamba and occasionally in La Paz too.  Although, they may just have been people from Tarija using it.

Comment: In Guatemala, Usted and Vos, are the standard forms used. Tu - is used with foreigners.

Comment: Una aclaración con respecto al voseo en Chile. Nosotros voseamos principalmente los verbos, pero, si hay un pronombre, éste generalmente es _tú_. Por ejemplo, decimos _¿tenís hambre?_ y _tú vai a ganar_. Pero el pronombre _vos_ lo usamos poco. Cuando se usa, no implica camaradería ni intimidad, sino agresividad, real o fingida (_¿vos soi weón?_). El uso de _vos_ podría calificarse en Chile como "de mala educación".