# ¿Cuáles países con voseo tienen voseo puro?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, conjugación, voseo

Existen varios tipos o niveles de voseo:

- el voseo puro, donde todas las conjugaciones se hacen modificando las conjugaciones de vosotros, y
- el voseo mixto donde simplemente se substituye vos por tú en algunas situaciones.

Por ejemplo, hablando con un argentino rioplatense noté que él usa la expresión "**vos quieras**" mientras yo (hondureño) uso la expresión "**vos querás**"; también, él usa "**hasta que vos te mueras**" (argentino) y yo "**hasta que vos te murás**" (centroamericano).
Sé que el último suena feo para muchos hispanoparlantes pero intento nunca modificar mi español (**vosotros muráis --> vos murás**).

Voseo puro:

- "vos querás"
- "vos murás"
- "vos comistes"
- "vos trabajastes"

Voseo mixto:

- "vos quieras"
- "vos mueras"
- "vos comiste"
- "vos trabajaste"

Un boliviano me dijo que en la región donde nació usan el voseo puro.

Mi duda entonces es:

**¿Cuáles países con voseo tienen actualmente el *voseo puro*?**

Comment: *que vos te murás* no me suena nada raro.  Sí que me suena raro *has* en vez de *hasta* (que supongo es un error tipográfico, pero siempre es posible que sea un regionalismo que desconozco yo).  Pero un *voseo puro* sería difícil, ya que en todas las regiones hoy voseantes se ha dejado de emplear el pronombre átono *os*, empleándose a su vez la forma tuteante *te*

Comment: Es error tipográfico, gracias. Entonces puedo llamarlo quase-puro? ;) , probablemente no te suena nada raro o porque sos español y estás acostumbrado a "vosotros", o porque sos de una región con voseo no tan mixto.

Comment: @Helmut No te creas, como hispanohablante de españa, "vos te murás" me suena como una patada en el culo. No creo que a guifa no le suene raro por hablar un español de península.

Comment: @kek Bueno, la variedad pensinular la hablo yo, pero cuando dije raro quería decir que no me sonaba nada más extraño que, por ejemplo, *que vos te mueras*, y así me suenan ambos solo por no tener soler escuchar el voseo.  No obstante, entre las formas *murás* y *mueras*, ninguna me suena más o menos raro, tal vez porque suelo escuchar *mueras* más, pero etimológicamente, debería ser *murás*.

Answer (score 2):

Soy hablante argentino rioplatense y realmente no estoy seguro de cuál es mi propia preferencia en cuanto a las diferentes conjugaciones; pensándolo bien es probable que varíe según el verbo y la estructura de la frase.

Creo que nunca digo *querás* o *murás*, pero se me ocurre que puede haber una cierta resistencia de origen analógico a usar la forma aguda cuando en la forma grave hay una alternancia con diptongación (*querer → qu**ie**ras, morir → m**ue**ras*). En los verbos que no alternan la vocal la diferencia entre las dos formas es sólo de acentuación (*que vivas / que vivás, cuando vengas / cuando vengás*) y allí es más fácil que haya una variación libre en el uso, porque un simple cambio de énfasis puede hacer que uno mismo no se dé cuenta conscientemente de dónde está poniendo el acento.

Esto en lo que se refiere al presente del subjuntivo. En el pretérito del indicativo cabe mencionar que la *-s* (*comistes, trabajastes*), si bien es etimológicamente más correcta, en rioplatense se suele ver como signo de afectación de clase alta (quizá porque la *-s* final en rioplatense suele aspirarse y desaparecer, con lo cual añadir una *-s* a algo que no la lleva sería una forma de hipercorrección).

Comment: Es interesante, en México se suele agregar **-s** en la pronunciación de de los verbos; En el norte de México, la **s** final es resonante y no aspirada y da, quizá, un sentimiento de completitud al hablante. Asi, locuciones como *fuistes, *moristes, *estuvistes son muy comunes. Sin embargo, el voseo no se usa aquí desde hace muchos años (salvo en algunas regiones del sur) por lo que más que una hipercorrección, en el caso de México, podría ser un tipo de involución. Además, su uso no es considerado como de clase alta sino al contrario.

Answer (score 1):

Argentina.

Aunque hay predominancia del mixto, por cuestiones (presumo) estéticas.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la pregunta se refiere a países, hay que notar que el voseo más que en países se usa en regiones.

Por lo anterior quiero hacer referencia otra pregunta similar en este mismo sitio donde Joze y yo adicionamos mapas de las regiones donde se usa el voseo y donde además se combina con otras formas.

Dicha pregunta es [Are there regions or dialects which use both “tú” and “vos”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/196/are-there-regions-or-dialects-which-use-both-t%C3%BA-and-vos/197#197)

La fuente del mapa original de Joze no la sé pero la del mapa actualizado es [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo).

Comment: ¿Antioquia sería un ejemplo de voseo puro? ¿O qué crees?

Comment: @MauricioMartinez _¿qué creés vos?_ :-D Si. Aquí en Antioquia y en el eje cafetero usamos voseo puro hablado. Curiosamente muy similar (prácticamente igual) estructuralmente al que usan en Argentina pero con entonación diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Les dejo la recopilación de conjugaciones voseantes usada por país y región según la RAE: https://www.rae.es/dpd/voseo

Hay que ir hasta el final para ver la tabla con el resumen.

Al ser argentino nacido y educado en Buenos Aires, coincido con un usuario anterior que dice que :

morir -> no te mueras / murás (suena feo)

querer -> lo que quieras / querás (usado más en áreas rurales)

calentarse (enojarse) -> no te calientes / calentés (ambos usados y percibidos como iguales)

moverse -> no te muevas / movás (usado más en áreas rurales)

poder -> llamame cuando vos puedas / podás (usado más en áreas rurales)

meterse -> no te metas / metás (ambos usados y percibidos como iguales)

hacerse -> no te hagas / hagás el boludo (ambos usados y percibidos como iguales)

sentirse -> no te sientas / sintás mal (suena feo)

sentarse -> no te sientes / sentés (ambos usados y percibidos como iguales)

venir -> no me vengas / vengás a decir que ... (ambos usados y percibidos como iguales)

En el pretérito del indicativo cabe mencionar que la -s (comistes, trabajastes), si bien es etimológicamente más correcta, en castellano rioplatense se suele ver como signo de afectación de clase alta (quizá porque la -s final en rioplatense suele aspirarse y desaparecer, con lo cual añadir una -s sería una forma de hipercorrección). Pero también hay personas que pronuncian la s mucho más que que los aspirantes. Digamos que es una percepción de los aspirantes hacia los que pronuncian la s.