# ¿Cuántos voseamos?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, hispanoamérica, voseo

Del voseo está casi todo dicho... El qué, cuándo, [cómo, dónde](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/196/are-there-regions-or-dialects-which-use-both-t%C3%BA-and-vos), por qué... pero ¿Cuántas personas voseamos? Hace unos años en la [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-47258239) mencionaban que en Latinoamérica voseaban las 2/3 partes de la población, [estimación hecha por María Vaquero](http://www.scielo.org.co/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0122-72382010000100012#spie18) en *El español de América* en 1996.

Si la académica tuviera razón en su época y la tendencia se mantiene, se hace regla de 3 y de los casi 410 millones de habitantes de la Hispanoamérica 'política' (de Tijuana hasta Tierra del Fuego), nos quedan unos 270 millones largos... (Cantidad más amplia de la que esperaba, para ser sinceros)

Ahora, se puede contemplar una Hispanoamérica lingüística (ya hay Academia Norteamericana de la Lengua Española, para los casi 55 millones de hispanohablantes en EEUU) y unos 10 millones más en el resto del continente. ¿Puede aplicarse esa misma razón a esos 65 millones de hispanohablantes del continente, para llegar a unos 310 millones de voseantes? ¿Hay estudios más recientes que permitan asegurar que la proporción de voseantes se mantiene, preferiblemente de la RAE o la ASALE, del tema?

Comment: No, no es necesario responder voseando... se vale responder de tú o de usted...

Comment: La BBC está hablando de hablantes del español.

Comment: @Lambie ¿Cómo sabés?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Se calcula que dos terceras partes de América Latina vosea.

Lo que me encanta de afirmaciones como éstas es que:

- Son muy difíciles de comprobar.
- Son ambiguas, con lo cual quien las escribe no tiene que comprometerse en modo alguno con lo que expresa.
- Y por lo tanto, predisponen al lector a que interprete lo que no se está afirmando.

Por un lado, América Latina siempre se entendió como ‘la región de América en donde se habla español y portugués’. A los brazucas ¿también los contamos? ¿Por qué no, si ellos emplean el *você*, cuando en Portugal se emplea el *tu*? El fenómeno es parecido.

Además, sigue siendo imposible decretar la proporción de voseantes sin haber definido lo que se entiende por ello. Los que reservan el voseo para el trato íntimo, los que lo hacen incluso sabiendo que en su país está mal visto o los que no lo hacen casi nunca excepto en contadas situaciones ¿deberíamos considerarlos? Supongamos que sí, definamos así ‘persona que vosea’ como aquella que lo hace en forma regular bajo algún contexto determinado, sin importar si tutea en otros contextos.

Para saber si es cierto lo que dijieron y en el momento que lo hicieron, tomemos los datos de la población de los países que interesan del año que importa [(2019)](https://datos.bancomundial.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?locations=ZJ), y hagamos una burda estimación basándonos en lo que aparece en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo). Allí se distingue al menos cuatro tipos de países:

- Donde el voseo es oficial (verde), consideramos el 100% de la población.
- Donde el voseo es generalizado pero no oficial (amarillo), consideramos el 95% de la población.
- Donde el voseo no es generalizado y aparece en regiones aisladas o no está bien visto (naranja), consideremos el 10%. Esta estimación va a depender mucho del país, así que es la más incierta.
- Donde no hay voseo (rojo), consideramos 0.

Por ahora, el resultado queda así:

[image]

**Considerando la situación más favorable, 59,54% de los latinoamericanos vosea**. En mi opinión, aún está lejos del supuesto 66,6% y la hipótesis nula debe ser rechazada.

Comment: Reitero que es una *estimación*, si alguien cree que alguna cifra no es realista me lo puede fundamentar y la cambio

Comment: Creo que dominica sobra... y como colombiano, ese 10 % es algo bajo, quizá llegue a un 20 o 25 %, no estoy seguro...no sé otros países

Comment: En Brasil, se trata de otra cosa. *Você* en vez de *tu* es como *usted* en vez de *tu* (ustedeo), no *vos* en vez de *tu* (voseo).

Comment: @jlliagre No estoy de acuerdo, [leé esto](https://rioandlearn.com/pt-br/diferenca-tu-voce-portugues/): *Mas pera aí, será que isso quer dizer que os brasileiros são sempre formais uns com os outros? Claro que não! Se um carioca não consegue nem usar sapatos ao invés de havaianas para ir ao supermercado, você realmente acha que nós tentaríamos ser formais? Você em português simplesmente perdeu seu tom formal, e começou a ser usado com todas as pessoas, independentemente da hierarquia social.*

Comment: Sí, estoy de acuerdo en que se trata de fenómenos similares, la sustitución de la segunda persona del singular por una forma inicialmente respetuosa. Lo que quería decir es que el artículo de la BBC habla de *voseo* (*tu* → *vos*), no de *ustedeo* (*tu* → *usted/você*).

Comment: Por otra parte, el portugués de Portugal ya ha sustituido generalmente la segunda persona del plural *vós* por *vocês* de la misma manera que *vosotros* se sustituye por *ustedes* en Hispanoamérica.

Comment: @jlliagre Creo que te referís a la etimología de los pronombres, en eso concuerdo en que el análisis no debería incluír al portugués. Es muy polémico, por eso hice las cuentas en dos casos: uno considera a Brasil y el otro lo excluye. Pero el objetivo original de la respuesta era otro: ver cómo es posible tergiversar una afirmación que ya es muy laxa para convertirla en verdadera. En mi opinión, es una exageración y ni así se puede llegar a 2/3 de voseantes en ‘Latinoamérica’

Comment: A nivel lingüístico, estás confundiendo Iberoamérica con Latinoamérica, pues tocaría incluir a Haití y si nos ponemos quisquillosos, el Quebec, la Guayana francesa, una que otra isla del Caribe y eso ya se sale del alcance de este sitio... pero me das una idea para una respuesta de corte wiki para el español... hacer una estimación muy pesimista (ej. no toda Argentina ni todo el Paraguay vosea...), una muy optimista (ej. que en EUA voseara el 30% de hispanos...) y una 'aterrizada' (a buscar artículos que demuestren que pasa en los países parcialmente voseantes)

Comment: @VeAqui La BBC dice ‘Latinoamérica’ no ‘Iberoamérica’, además no tiene sentido incluír las regiones donde se habla francés si no existe ningún fenómeno parecido al voseo. Pero por supuesto, es una estimación en el mejor de los casos para mostrar que esa cifra de 2/3 es un disparate y no hay forma de defenderla

Comment: @tac, al intentar buscar la opción 'aterrizada' para la respuesta, me toca replantear la pregunta y no se le puede dar la razón a la BBC, pero debieron investigar un poco para no dejar el error

Comment: @VeAqui No parece muy aterrizado ese estudio que citás, les autores mencionan los dos tercios en el resumen pero sólo como un número sacado de la galera, en ningún momento centran su trabajo en mostrar sus estudios estadísticos sobre esa cifra ni citan la referencia de dónde lo sacaron

Comment: @tac, el pie de página cita el libro donde está el estudio... (VAQUERO, María. (1996): "El español de América". en Cuadernos de Lengua Española: Tomo II. Madrid, Arco Libros S.A pp. 22-26, 28. ) El detalle está en poder conseguir el libro.

Comment: @VeAqui No te dejés llevar por el argumento de autoridad. El texto citado es [éste](http://corchado.org/upr/pdf/espanol_america_II_vaquero.pdf). Leé la sección 2.3.3 en donde se mencionan las variantes del voseo en diversos países. Primero, en ningún momento dice que dos terceras partes de L.A. vosea. Segundo, las estimaciones que da la autora son meramente *cualitativas* y no me queda claro que sean más acertadas que la mía. Y tercero, incluso si en algún lado figurara que 'dos terceras partes vosea', debemos desconfiar puesto que de nuevo: el foco de ese mismo texto que decís no es censar